# How to debug an extension immediately upon installation

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension which includes a newtab.js file. The extension works fine most of the time but I have an issue that occurs when my extension is first installed. Now I have the problem of how to set a breakpoint in newtab.js before it is run for the first time.  I have tried putting "debugger;" statements in the code but chrome appears to be ignoring them when the code is first run (and halts when run a subsequent time but by then it is too late and the issue has already occurred).

FYI, when the program is first installed, Chrome shows my onboarding page (onboarding.html) and that all works fine. The problem occurs when I then click on "new tab" and my newtab.html is loaded which loads newtab.js.

Comment: Open devtools first then reload the page. Without more info or [MCVE](/help/mcve) it's unclear why debugging is problematic. If you want to debug the service worker's first run it's indeed slightly convoluted.

Comment: You say "reaload" the page but that means the page (and newtab.js) has already run once... but there is something that goes wrong specifically in the *first* time the code is executed - I want to debug that.

Comment: There's a "trick" I use for local unpacked extensions: remove or comment out the code and let the page open empty, then restore the code, open devtools, reload the page.

Comment: Wow, that worked. It doesn't feel right but it worked.